# Socket permissions exception when attempting to read a page via HttpClient.GetStringAsync

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, httpexception

I am trying a Windows 8 App which gets source code of a webpage and extract some important data. But I am receiving this when `getStringAsync` function get called.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   173.194.41.64:443    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Here is the code

```csharp
const string feedUrl = "https://google.com";
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
Client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
Client.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
var source = await Client.GetStringAsync(feedUrl);
```

Comment: Are you using any proxy for internet access??

Comment: NO, I am not using any proxy server.

Comment: Try the below code , if its working it means you dant have any firewall or internet security issue,as its working fine for me.                 String feedUrl = "https://google.com";
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 GetMethod method = new GetMethod(feedUrl);
 method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
      new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
 int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
 System.out.println(new String(method.getResponseBody()));